# Laravel sending mail

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have problem with laravel mail, I configurate env file like this (ofc email and password i replace to my own email data):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

run artisan function

```
php artisan config:cache
```

I create in controller method:

```
public function mailTest(  ) {
        $data = array('email' => 'email@gmail.com', 'nickName' => 'nickname');
        Mail::send('emails.test', ['data' => $data], function($message) use ($data) {
            $message -> from('mail@gmail.com', 'Administrator');
            $message -> to($data['email'], $data['nickName']);
            $message -> subject('Custom subject');
        });
    }
```

On my email account where from i sent message i have copy of this message in outbox (sent) folder but on second mail i don't receive this mail even in spam folder.

Can anyone tell what's wrong with this ?

PS. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

To send emails using Gmail SMTP you need to configure some settings in your Google account. Follow these steps.

- Login to your Google account.
- Go to the [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/) page. Click the Signing in to Google link from Sign-in & securitysection.

[image]

- Scroll down the Password & sign-in method section and turn Off the 2-Step Verification.

[image]

- Scroll down the Connected apps & sites section and turn On Allow less secure apps.

[image]

Reference: https://www.codexworld.com/send-html-email-php-gmail-smtp-phpmailer/

Comment: I already have disabled 2-Step Verification and enabled "Allow less secure apps"